# Django Template not preserving OrderedDict

Tags: python, django

The function returns an ordered list

```
    my_olist = OrderedDict() 
    my_olist['bananas'] = 3
    my_olist['apples'] = 1
    ..
    return my_olist
```

in the view.py I confirmed the order is maintained

```
   returned_ordered_list = mylist()  # this is still ordered
    request.session['results'] = {...
             'ordered_list': returned_ordered_list
}
return render(request, HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp:resultspage',))
```

However in the HTML template resultspage, the order is no longer maintained

```
{% for key, value in ordered_list.items %} 
<b>{{key}}:</b> {{value}} <br>
 {% endfor %}
```

I've seen a solution working for orderedDict but they did not use HttpResponseRedirect.

Comment: The line `return render(request, HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp:resultspage',))` does not make sense. The second argument to `render` should be the template name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store an ordered dict in the session, then the order will not be preserved. By default, the Django session is serialized as JSON. When it is deserialized, you get a regular dictionary, so the ordering will be lost.

If the ordering is important, and you don't have to access the dictionary values by key, then you could use a list of tuples instead:

```
my_olist = [] 
my_olist.append(('bananas', 3))
my_olist.append(('apples', 1))
```

Then update the template to loop through the list:

```
{% for key, value in ordered_list %}
```

Answer (score 2):

firebase data 
[image: image of firebase realtime storage]

python.py

```
firebase = Firebase(config)
db = firebase.database()
x = db.child("Home page").get()
output = {
     'value':x
   }
return render(request, "index.html",output)
```

index.html

```
 <p class="m-t-10 m-b-0 font-18 wow fadeInUp " id="K">{{ value.val.KhadiMadeFashionable } </p>
```

Comment: Please include the text as text, not as pictures.